# Does Connecting to Remote WMI from an ASP.NET Page using Constrained Delegation Require Protocol Transition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp-classic, wmi

I'm working on an older web app that I did not originally build, but now maintain. It is a classic ASP app with ASPX pages mixed in.

The site is setup for Kerberos authentication and delegation, and that is working properly to other boxes (e.g. I can run a SQL query against a back-end server from an ASP page in the site and it connects using the front-end client's credentials properly). So SPNs are registered, delegation privileges are configured in AD, etc.

Now, the part I'm having trouble with is an ASPX page which invokes a remote WMI call to check on the status of an IIS website, using the \root\WebAdministration WMI namespace. The ASPX page is itself invoked by way of an XHR which resides in the client-side code of a different ASP page. The ASPX, when invoked, makes the WMI call, then Response.Write's back the necessary data, which the originating ASP page then utilizes to populate the page that the user sees. **The problem is, I cannot get the IIS box to properly delegate the user's credentials to the back-end machine that its making the WMI call against.**

This all works properly (including the constrained delegation), but only if I enable protocol transition. If I set the delegation on the middle-tier (IIS) box to use only Kerberos authentication, it fails (I get an anonymous logon attempt on the back-end box).

Now, I've done numerous packet captures on both the front-end client and the IIS box to see exactly what is going on here, and I can see several things:

- The front-end client is properly getting its Kerberos ticket, and presenting it to the IIS box for authentication.
- The IIS box is accepting the Kerberos ticket from the client.
- However, the IIS box is **not** using the ticket received from the client as the "evidence ticket" that it should be presenting to the KDC in order to obtain a service ticket to access the back-end service on behalf of the front-end user. **Instead, the IIS box is using a S4U2Self call to the KDC to obtain a ticket on the front-end user's behalf for itself, then using that ticket in the subsequent S4U2Proxy call to try and obtain the ticket to the back-end. This is where the problem lies.**
- The behavior noted above is why this works when protocol transition is enabled, and does not work when it is not.

I cannot figure out for the life of me, why the IIS box feels the need to obtain a TGS for itself to use as the "evidence ticket" to get the ticket for accessing the back-end, instead of simply using the ticket presented by the client. There is nothing invalid about the client's ticket from what I can tell, and the client is establishing a Kerberos-authenticated connection with the web server just fine, so there should be no need for protocol transition here. I could enable it if really needed, but I really just want to know why its necessary (if there is valid reason and this is by design then so be it).

The IIS app pool is running as the built-in app pool identity, and the delegation settings are thus configured on the IIS machine account in AD. SPNs are registered for the site against the IIS machine account, and for the back-end services against those service and/or machine accounts, and the "allowedToDelegateTo" list is configured on the IIS machine account, allowing constrained delegation to the necessary services. The specific SPN we are trying to delegate creds to in this scenario is RPCSS/[machine] for the WMI call. I've verified via the packet capture that the SPN in the request matches the SPN in the A2D2 list *exactly* (of course, if it didn't, then it wouldn't be working when protocol transition was enabled anyway).

As for the actual WMI connection code, I've tried a few ways. One was something like this:

```
ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions();
// I did try ImpersonationLevel set to both Impersonate and Delegate, but I don't think I need
// Delegate here because I'm not delegating from the remote WMI machine to a different box; instead,
// I'm delegating from the IIS box to the remote WMI machine.
co.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
co.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
co.EnablePrivileges = true;
// Tried this for the Authority line because I noticed in the packet captures that the principal
// specified here becomes the SPN that is used in the S4U2Proxy request.
co.Authority = "kerberos:RPCSS/machine.domain.com";
ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(@"\\machine.domain.com\root\WebAdministration", co);
```

Then I also tried this:

```
ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions();
co.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
co.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
co.EnablePrivileges = true;
// I also tried this for the Authority line based on various other code examples for similar
// issues, but this resulted in an incorrect SPN being used in the request.
co.Authority = @"kerberos:DOMAIN\machine";
ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(@"\\machine.domain.com\root\WebAdministration", co);
```

I also tried the same as above, but without an Authority line, and the correct SPN was used in the request but it still didn't work.

Finally, I also tried this, with no ConnectionOptions object at all, hoping it would just pass on the default creds:

```
ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(@"\\machine.domain.com\root\WebAdministration");
```

Any help here on either how I can get this working without enabling protocol transition, or info on why this setup would require protocol transition, would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Based on your long description, there is no obvious way to get rid of protocol transition. "which invokes a remote WMI call to check on the status of an IIS website, using the \root\WebAdministration WMI namespace" is no longer the way to go with the IIS REST API from Microsoft, https://github.com/Microsoft/IIS.Administration

Comment: Interesting, I'm not familiar with the IIS API so I'll have to check that out (thanks for pointing me at that btw). Yes, from my testing it does indeed seem that protocol transition may be required here. I was more just wondering why... (why the IIS box refuses to utilize the client's service ticket for this particular delegation scenario).